# SQL - How to aggregate and count appearances

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

For the below example, `VOLUME_ON`, `VOLUME_OFF`, `COST_TYPE` can be a certain set of values (note `VOLUMES_ON/OFF` values are different to `COST_TYPE` values).

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
    PROJECT_ID  VARCHAR2 (10), 
    NAME        VARCHAR2(10), 
    PRIMARY KEY (PROJECT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_COSTS (
    COST_ID     VARCHAR2 (10), 
    COST_TYPE   VARCHAR2 (10), 
    PRIMARY KEY (COST_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_DETAILS (
    DETAIL_ID   VARCHAR2 (10), 
    VOLUME_ON   VARCHAR2(10), 
    VOLUME_OFF  VARCHAR2(10), 
    PRJ_ID VARCHAR2 (10) FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES PROJECT(PROJECT_ID),
    CST_ID FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES PROJECT_COSTS(COST_ID)
);
```

For each `PROJECT.PROJECT_ID`, I want to count the number of occurrences of `VOLUME_ON`, `VOLUME_OFF` for certain values within `COST_TYPE`. Something along the lines of.

```
SELECT COUNT(VOLUME_ON),
       COUNT(VOLUME_OFF),
       COUNT(TBC.VOLUME_ON),
       COUNT(TBC.VOLUME_OFF)
FROM PROJECT p
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_DETAILS pd ON p.PROJECT_ID = pd.PROJECT_ID
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_COSTS pc ON pd.CST.ID = pc.COST_ID
AND pc.COST_TYPE IN ('ab', 'cd')
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_COSTS pc2 ON pd.CST.ID = pc2.COST_ID
AND pc2.COST_TYPE IN ('ef', 'gh')
GROUP BY p.PROJECT_ID
```

How can i return the counts of `VOLUME_ON` and `VOLUME_OFF` for different COST_TYPE for each `PROJECT_ID`?

Comment: What is the problem of current query? Try adding `COST_TYPE`. And why self join of `PROJECT_COSTS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an example that shows the "left join on constant" problem.

Very often, joining on a constant is semantically not what is really required. In this example, instead of joining on the COST_TYPE, we should be *filtering* on the COST_TYPE. Why does this matter? Because they give different results! This can be shown with an example. Lets ad some data to this example:

```
drop table project_details;
drop table project_costs;
drop table project;

CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
    PROJECT_ID  VARCHAR2 (10),
    NAME        VARCHAR2(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (PROJECT_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_COSTS (
    COST_ID     VARCHAR2 (10),
    COST_TYPE   VARCHAR2 (10),
    PRIMARY KEY (COST_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_DETAILS (
    DETAIL_ID   VARCHAR2 (10),
    VOLUME_ON   VARCHAR2(10),
    VOLUME_OFF  VARCHAR2(10),
    PRJ_ID VARCHAR2 (10),
    CST_ID VARCHAR2(10),
    FOREIGN KEY (PRJ_ID) REFERENCES PROJECT(PROJECT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CST_ID ) REFERENCES PROJECT_COSTS(COST_ID)
);

insert into project values( '1', 'Proj1' );
insert into project values( '2', 'Proj2' );
insert into project values( '3', 'Proj3' );
insert into project values( '4', 'Proj4' );

commit;

insert into project_costs values( 'C1', 'ab' );
insert into project_costs values( 'C2', 'cd' );
insert into project_costs values( 'C3', 'ef' );
insert into project_costs values( 'C4', 'gh' );
insert into project_costs values( 'C5', 'zz' );

commit;

insert into project_details values( 'D1', 'V1', 'V2', '1','C1' );
insert into project_details values( 'D2', 'V1', 'V2', '1','C2' );
insert into project_details values( 'D3', 'V1', 'V2', '1','C3' );
insert into project_details values( 'D4', 'V1', 'V2', '2','C1' );
insert into project_details values( 'D5', 'V1', 'V2', '3','C1' );
insert into project_details values( 'D6', 'V1', 'V2', '1','C1' );

commit;
```

Ignoring the aggregation for now, and just performing the joins...

```
SELECT  p.name
      , pc.cost_id
      , pc.cost_type
      , pd.detail_id
FROM PROJECT p
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_DETAILS pd
  ON p.PROJECT_ID = pd.PRJ_ID
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_COSTS pc
  ON pd.CST_ID = pc.COST_ID
  AND pc.COST_TYPE IN ('ab', 'cd')


NAME       COST_ID    COST_TYPE  DETAIL_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Proj1      C1         ab         D6
Proj3      C1         ab         D5
Proj2      C1         ab         D4
Proj1      C1         ab         D1
Proj1      C2         cd         D2
Proj4
Proj1                            D3

7 rows selected.
```

You can see that we get additional rows produced by the left join *after* "joining" on COST_TYPE in ('ab','cd').  If we change the JOIN to a filter...

```
SELECT  p.name
      , pc.cost_id
      , pc.cost_type
      , pd.detail_id
FROM PROJECT p
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_DETAILS pd
  ON p.PROJECT_ID = pd.PRJ_ID
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_COSTS pc
  ON pd.CST_ID = pc.COST_ID
  WHERE pc.COST_TYPE IN ('ab', 'cd')   <--- Now a filter


  NAME       COST_ID    COST_TYPE  DETAIL_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Proj1      C1         ab         D1
Proj1      C2         cd         D2
Proj2      C1         ab         D4
Proj3      C1         ab         D5
Proj1      C1         ab         D6
```

Since we have defined a relationship between `PROJECT_DETAILS` and `PROJECT_COSTS`, we know that every `PROJECT_DETAIL` record must have a `PROJECT_COST` and so the LEFT OUTER join is not needed. In fact the optimizer will transform the plan to use an inner join for you.

So in the end, I think the query should look something like

```
SELECT p.name
        , pc.cost_type
        , count(pd.volume_on)
        , count(pd.volume_off)
FROM PROJECT p
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_DETAILS pd
  ON p.PROJECT_ID = pd.PRJ_ID
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_COSTS pc
  ON pd.CST_ID = pc.COST_ID
  where pc.COST_TYPE IN ('ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh')
group by p.name
        , pc.cost_type
order by 1,2


NAME       COST_TYPE  COUNT(PD.VOLUME_ON) COUNT(PD.VOLUME_OFF)
---------- ---------- ------------------- --------------------
Proj1      ab                           2                    2
Proj1      cd                           1                    1
Proj1      ef                           1                    1
Proj2      ab                           1                    1
Proj3      ab                           1                    1
```

However, the important thing I am trying to highlight here, is the semantic difference between the ON clause and the WHERE clause in an OUTER join.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate separate counts for each `COST_TYPE` by adding `COST_TYPE` to your `GROUP BY` clause.  You should also add project and cost type information to your output, so you can tell different projects/cost types apart.

E.g.,

```
SELECT p.name, 
       pc.cost_type, 
       COUNT(VOLUME_ON), 
       COUNT(VOLUME_OFF), 
       COUNT(TBC.VOLUME_ON), 
       COUNT(TBC.VOLUME_OFF)
FROM PROJECT p
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_DETAILS pd
  ON p.PROJECT_ID = pd.PROJECT_ID
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_COSTS pc
  ON pd.CST.ID = pc.COST_ID
  AND pc.COST_TYPE IN ('ab', 'cd')
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_COSTS pc2
  ON pd.CST.ID = pc2.COST_ID
  AND pc2.COST_TYPE IN ('ef', 'gh')
GROUP BY p.PROJECT_ID, pc.cost_type
```